# Xsd. Declaration of inheritance of two entities hierarchies

Tags: inheritance, xsd

Assume I have two class hierarchies:

```
class Cell {
    string data;
}

// extends Cell with additional property `label`
class Cell2 : Cell {
    string label;
}

class Row {
    Cell[] cells;
}

// extends Cell with additional property `label`
// `cells` property is an array of `Cell2`
class Row2 : Row {
    string label;
}
```

Row contains an array of Cell instances, and Row2 contains an array of Cell2 instances. Here is xsd of this entities:

```
<xs:complexType name="cell">
    <xs:attribute name="data"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="cell2">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="cell">
            <xs:attribute name="label"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="row">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="cell" type="cell"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- Here is the problem: row2 should cointains cell2 -->
<xs:complexType name="row2">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="row">
            <xs:attribute name="label"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

However this xsd ignore that Row2 should contains an array of Cell2 instances, not Cell instances. How I can declare such relations using xsd?

Comment: Is there a rule that Row must _always_ contain Cell instances and Row2 must _always_ contain Cell2 instances?

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly declare that Row2 contains Cell2, like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="cell">
    <xs:attribute name="data"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="cell2">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="cell">
            <xs:attribute name="label"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="row">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="cell" type="cell"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="row2">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="cell" type="cell2"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="label"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I suspect that you know this already and you probably want to create something more complex than this example. If I'm right then I suggest that you read about complex type inheritance in the XSD specification or other online tutorials. There are various ways to model object-oriented structures in XSD models.